# Disable embedded keyboard on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

How can I disable the embedded keyboard on my netbook so that I can put an external keyboard on top of it?

I'd like a solution that works across the whole system -- not just in a single X session but also in the virtual terminals.

Answer (score 1):

For X11 you can use `xinput list` to find the keyboard id and `xinput --disable ...` to disable it. For the console keyboard I dont know of anything to disable it, but you can use `loadkeys` to install a dummy keyboard mapping that should stop most
accidental input. See man `dumpkeys` and `keymaps(5)`.

Comment: Installing a dummy keyboard mapping sounds like something that'll disable both the embedded and the external keyboard, will it not?

Comment: oops. that is probably true.